# Syntax error when concatenating a string in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have the following code inside a cdef class (Cython language):

```
def toString(self):
    res = "lut= " + str(self._mm_np[0].lut) +
        "n1= "  + str(self._mm_np[0].n1) +
        "nlay= "+ str(self._mm_np[0].nlay) +
        "n3= "  + str(self._mm_np[0].n3)
    return res
```

when I try to compile the cython file containing this code I get the following syntax error:
"Expected an identifier or literal" that pointing on the spot with the first '+' in string concatenation.

I have tried to use '\' instead of '+' with no success..
What is the right way to concatenate strings in Pyhton/Cython?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the line continuation operator `\`:

```
def toString(self):
    res = "lut= " + str(self._mm_np[0].lut) + \
    "n1= "  + str(self._mm_np[0].n1) + \
    "nlay= "+ str(self._mm_np[0].nlay) + \
    "n3= "  + str(self._mm_np[0].n3)
    return res
```

...but you really shouldn't do that.  It's considered poor style.

Explore the usage of the `.format` method for strings instead; it will provide positional arguments to that string so you don't *have* to concatenate.

```
def toString(self): 
    return "lut={} n1={} nlay={} n3={}".format(
                str(self._mm_np[0].lut),
                str(self._mm_np[0].n1),
                str(self._mm_np[0].nlay),
                str(self._mm_np[0].n3))
```